# application not working on tablet

Tags: android, tablet

when I try to run My app on tablet with android version 4 
it will not work and give this error in log cat

```
07-04 13:16:28.029: E/AndroidRuntime(688): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-94
07-04 13:16:28.029: E/AndroidRuntime(688): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
07-04 13:16:28.029: E/AndroidRuntime(688):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1076)
07-04 13:16:28.029: E/AndroidRuntime(688):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1063)
07-04 13:16:28.029: E/AndroidRuntime(688):  at com.henanet.dalel.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:48)
07-04 13:16:28.499: I/dalvikvm(688): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-04 13:16:29.121: D/dalvikvm(688): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 680K, 13% free 6869K/7815K, paused 408ms
07-04 13:16:29.139: E/dalvikvm(688): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Is a directory
07-04 13:16:29.139: I/dalvikvm(688): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-04 13:16:29.370: E/dalvikvm(688): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Is a directory
07-04 13:16:30.569: D/dalvikvm(688): GC_CONCURRENT freed 262K, 11% free 7016K/7815K, paused 3ms+4ms
07-04 13:16:31.900: W/dalvikvm(688): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
07-04 13:16:31.900: I/Process(688): Sending signal. PID: 688 SIG: 9
```

this Splash.java as you can see very simple , and please tell me how to make images fit tablet

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

```
//how long until we go to the next activity
protected int _splashTime = 5000; 

private Thread splashTread;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    final SplashScreen sPlashScreen = this; 

    // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
    splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized(this){

                        //wait 5 sec
                        wait(_splashTime);
                }

            } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
            finally {
                finish();

                //start a new activity
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(sPlashScreen, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                stop();
            }
        }
    };

    splashTread.start();
}

//Function that will handle the touch
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        synchronized(splashTread){
                splashTread.notifyAll();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Please post `SplashScreen.java` around line 48

Comment: We can't be sure until we see your SplashScreen code, but are you sure you're not using some feature a tablet doesn't have? Think of things such as (back-)camera, telephony (sms/calls), some even do not have portrait mode..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The splash screen image is not find in suitable drawable folder.

drawable-large-mdpi or hdpi folder for 7 inch tablets.

drawable-xlarge-mdpi or hdpi folder for 10 inch tablets.

use the correct images.

and check in manifest file for the tag

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```